# Use furnace cart to travel long distances

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing minecraft and I decided to make another base connected by a railroad. I have almost no gold so I figured I would use a cart with a furnace to push me. I place the cart with a furnace on the ground and my mine-cart in front of it. Then I right click on my cart with furnace and sprint ahead to get in my cart. The only problem is that when it comes to push my cart it bangs into my cart and I go flying. The issue is then my cart with furnace goes into an unloaded chunk and my cart eventually stops moving. Then I am stuck. How do I fix this?

I am using 1.8

Comment: use boosters tracks instead of furnace carts

Comment: @ratchetfreak he says he doesn't have gold.

Comment: Am i the only one thinking this is actually a great question?

Comment: It is a great question. Let me outline a few assumptions:
1) Your computer isn't running out of game ticks? Open the console and see if there are messages warning you that the game is running slow ("can't keep up") 2) The furnace cart is right behind you and is pushing the cart you're in. Occasionally you lose contact with that cart and it is left behind? How does the cart go into an unloaded chunk if it is behind you? 3) The cart does not run out of fuel. If the cart runs out of fuel,  it stops. 4) "Eventually stops moving" means that you stop "shortly" after the furnace cart disappears?

Comment: I've experienced the same behavior the OP has, while trying to move villagers. The furnace minecart will tend to give one huge push, then lag behind for quite some time, and  can get quite far behind if the track goes downhill. It can get far enough behind that it would get unloaded, or take so long to catch up that it runs out of fuel. This seems to be a side effect of the new/revamped cart mechanics. You can see it to a lesser extent by pushing a minecart yourself. Sometimes you can give it a big push and it will go quite a ways without you - not as far as a furnace cart can push though.

Comment: My advice: go mining for gold. You get 1 powered track per gold ingot, and you only need them about every 8 blocks or so (except for going uphill, of course). You can find gold below level 40. Caving below that level is a pretty good way to find a decent amount quickly.

Comment: Does the minecart stacking bug still exist in 1.8? if so, that can save you a lot of tracks

Answer (score 5):

This method works for flat ground

1. Place the furnace minecart on track infront of the cart you will
   travel in
2. Get in the cart
3. Press <kbd>w</kbd> to shuffle your cart forward whilst facing the furnace cart
4. Let the carts "rub" for half a second or so
5. Whilst the carts are "rubbing" together click the furnace cart with fuel
6. Enjoy the ride

### The Setup

[image]

### Rubbing the carts together, time to add fuel

[image]

### Choo Choo

[image]

**Notes:**
Works on 1.8
Speed has not been checked
Non-flat track has not been checked

Comment: This is a really good idea, unfortunately when you go over a hill you disconnect from the cart (which makes it hard to use in a survival world that is not superflat)..

Answer (score 0):

In order to ride a minecart connected to a furnace minecart, you can just put the minecart with furnace behind you and activate it. The minecart whams into you and you go flying. You eventually may need to refuel the furnace minecart, but I know you won't get dismounted whenever you go up- or downhill. Sadly, you have to refuel the furnace minecart whenever you turn.